# How can I trigger a rule when there's no more scheduled content?

Tags: 7, views, rules

I have a Drupal 7 blog where I write content in advance and publish it using the Scheduler module. I'd like to be able to write a rule to send me an email when the site has published the last scheduled node available. I have a View set up which lists all the scheduled nodes, but I can't figure out how to get the result count of that view into the condition of a rule. I've got Views Bulk Operations and Views Rules installed, but I can't figure out how to use either of those how I need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make this work also by using [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) in combination with the [Views Bulk Operations](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) module, as further detailed below.

#### Step 1

Use the [Views Bulk Operations](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) module to create a view of all your "nodes to be published" (as in your question), in which you add a VBO field to it. Simply include a field like `nid` for each node (no need for any other fields). Just make sure you get exactly 1 row for each node you want to take into consideration.

#### Step 2

Create a Rules Component with a Rules Condition "***Check number of results returned by a VBO view***". And select the VBO view created in the previous step. If the number of results is below 1, then perform a Rules Action (in that Rules Component) to trigger your eMail.

#### Step 3

Create a Rule like so:

- Use some relevant **Rules Event** related to those nodes to be published.
- Don't use any **Rules Conditions** (there is no need for them in this rule).
- Perform a **Rules Action** to execute the Rules Component from Step 2.

If you cannot think of any relevant **Rules Event** that would fit for such rule, then just create a Rules Component which has (only) 2 Rules Actions:

- Perform a **Rules Action** to execute the Rules Component from Step 2.
- Reschedule this (extra) Rules Component itself, eg after X mins or hours

Then trigger the very first execution of this Rules Component using the Rules UI.

***Done!***

Comment: Ah! I was so close; I just didn't have any VBO fields on that view. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you also have the [Views Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_rules) module enabled, you could use a completely different approach like so also:

- Before starting the [Views Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_rules) loop (Rules Action) to iterate over all results of the view, define some boolean (or integer) variable which you set (initial value) to FALSE (or 0).
- Within each iteration of your [Views Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_rules) loop, set the value of the variable to TRUE (or 1).
- After the [Views Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_rules) loop completed, use the [Conditional Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_conditional) module to check the value of your extra variable: if it is still FALSE (or 0), you know there were no nodes to be processed, so that's when you want to send that eMail.